# Android WorkManager IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, firebase, android-workmanager

After I upgraded WorkManager version to 1.0.0-beta01 and 1.0.0-beta02, a ton of crashes appeared in my app.

It always happens in version 5.0 or 5.1 of Android.

The crash is as follows:

**java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:**
at androidx.work.impl.background.firebase.FirebaseJobService.onStartJob (FirebaseJobService.java:65)
**at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService$2.run (JobService.java:164)**

Please help me, and if you have anywhere else I can report this, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FirebaseJobDispatcher library is not supported anymore. 
Just remove the **work-firebase** dependency from build.gradle file and problem solved!